# UITableView - Bottom Rounded Corners

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am trying to achieve bottom rounded corners on `UITableView`.

I used below code snippet, Which exists in my MyUtils.m -

```
/*
* To get rounded corners of view.
*/
+ (UIView *)roundCornersOnView:(UIView *)view rectCorner:(UIRectCorner)corner radius:(float)radius
{
   UIView *roundedView = view;
   UIBezierPath *maskPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:roundedView.bounds byRoundingCorners:corner cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(radius, radius)];
   CAShapeLayer *maskLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
   maskLayer.frame = roundedView.bounds;
   maskLayer.path = maskPath.CGPath;
   roundedView.layer.mask = maskLayer;
   return roundedView;
}
```

Then I called above `MyUtils` method from my swift file to round corners of 2 Views. One is `UIView` and another is `UITableView`.

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        MyUtils.roundCornersOnView(myUIView, rectCorner: [.TopLeft, .TopRight], radius: 15)
        MyUtils.roundCornersOnView(myTableView, rectCorner: [.BottomLeft, .BottomRight], radius: 15)
}
```

No issue with `UIView`, in case of `UITableView` I can see bottom rounded corners at the bottom which I want to achieve but after that `UITableView` starts scroll not its content.

Usually content of `UITableView` scrolls but after applying this `UITableView` starts scroll, might be background of `UITableView` is scrolling.

Comment: apply clipToBounds to your myTableView so content that exceed the bounds of myTableView will not be visible.

Comment: @nferocious76 Thank you for looking into that, but uncertainly that didn't worked

Comment: could show me some screenshots of that part?

Comment: please join this room: https://join.skype.com/OnghTaGAf3VB

Comment: please check the file :)

Answer (score 0):

Overriding the mask layer of the tableView change's its tableViewWrapper properties and that introduces a weird behavior so for us to solve this we need to add a container view and implement our masking:

```
@interface ViewController ()<UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *container;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *testTable;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    CAShapeLayer * maskLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
    // manually configuring the mask rect will be the best way to set it rather than setting it in viewDidLayoutSubviews or viewDidAppear that can be called again when view is dismissed or popback.
    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 40, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width - 40, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height - 204);

    maskLayer.path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect: rect byRoundingCorners: UIRectCornerBottomLeft | UIRectCornerBottomRight cornerRadii: (CGSize){10.0, 10.}].CGPath;

    self.container.layer.mask = maskLayer;
    self.container.clipsToBounds = YES;

}


- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    return 15;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];

    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}

@end
```

Comment: We can set UIView as a backgroundView of Table, Can't we update that backgroundView without introducing new parent view?

Comment: No. backgroundVew change's its offset whenever you scroll it, though you can manually resize it also, it is behind the content of the tableView so your corners will be underneath and useless.